# Bin SH Script and wget URL parameter

Tags: bash, sh, wget

im currently using a bin sh script to convert php to static content. The script is currently this

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/clients/client3/web1/web/cache/static/ && \
rm -rf bluetracker-wow.html && \
wget http://m.domain.eu/bluetracker-wow.php?news_region=de -O bluetracker-wow.html -q
```

This is working,-  but i have some trouble with parameters. If i append a further parameter like "?news_region=de&lang=en" the result will be, that the file is gonna be saved as php file instead of html. So my noobie question is,- is there a way to use the "&" within the target url without bugging the script?

Comment: The backslashes at the end of each line are unnecessary. `&&` cannot end a command, so the parser knows there is more input on the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&` is  a *special* character in `shell`.

Enclose the `url` string into quotes:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/clients/client3/web1/web/cache/static/ && \
rm -rf bluetracker-wow.html && \
wget 'http://m.domain.eu/bluetracker-wow.php?news_region=de?news_region=de&lang=en' -O bluetracker-wow.html -q
```

If you prefer *weak quoting* you will need to escape the special chars.

Check: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

Comment: Thank you so much :) this is working. I will read a bit about special chars. *cheers*